# Configuration - Committing/pushing a single directory to github

Tags: github

I have a working repository setup at github.com

I want to push an entire directory to the server (not the sub-directories).  How can I do this with out selecting each file individually?

I am working with in a single folder...when I am complete I'm not sure which files I've modified...the directory is relatively small so I just want to simply commit and push everything in the quickest way possible.

How do I do this?

How do I commit and push all files in a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git commit -am "Commit message"` will add all the files that have changed to the index, and then commit them.  It won't do anything with files that are not currently being tracked.

Follow it up with `git push <githubRepo>` and it will push all those changes.

Answer (score 0):

the fast way is to make an alias for:

```
git add -A && git commit
```

The -A will add any modifications including new files added. The -a on commit will NOT include new files.